# RegEx for digits, three different conditions

Tags: regex, groovy, jenkins, post-build-event

Question : I want to check following conditions with RegEx in groovy.
This script is written in [Jenkins Groovy postbuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) script.

```
String pattern is "JOB_EXIT : $RESULT"
```

Logic to check :

```
If ( $RESULT contains only zeros ) {
   // do something
} else if ( $RESULT contains only non-zeros ) {
   // do something else
} else if ( $RESULT contains at least one zero and with some non-zeros ) {
   // do something else
}
```

Failed attempts :

```
def matcherFail = manager.getLogMatcher(".*JOB_EXIT : ([1-9]+)")
def matcherSuccess = manager.getLogMatcher(".*JOB_EXIT : ([0]*)")

if(matcherFail?.matches()) {
   // do something
} else if(matcherSuccess?.matches()) {
   // do something else
} else if(No idea about this one) {
   // do something else
}
```

Anyone can suggest the RegEx to check above conditions ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a switch as well (which shows the regex patterns)

```
// Some test data
def tests = [ [ input:'JOB_EXIT : 0000', expected:'ZEROS' ],
              [ input:'JOB_EXIT : 1111', expected:'NON-ZEROS' ],
              [ input:'JOB_EXIT : 0010', expected:'MIX' ] ]

// Check each item in test data
tests.each { test ->

    // based on the test input
    switch( test.input ) {
        case ~/JOB_EXIT : (0+)/ :
            println "$test.input is all ZEROS"
            assert test.expected == 'ZEROS'
            break

        case ~/JOB_EXIT : ([^0]+)/ :
            println "$test.input is all NON-ZEROS"
            assert test.expected == 'NON-ZEROS'
            break

        case ~/JOB_EXIT : ([0-9]+)/ :
            println "$test.input is a MIX"
            assert test.expected == 'MIX'
            break

        default :
            println "No idea for $test.input"
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking, Can we consider third case as default ?? $RESULT will be always string containing only digits and length never be zero...

Comment: You could do, but sometimes it's better to fail as soon as you can in case something goes wrong. Better to fail here than push errors down the pipeline where they might not be noticed?